# How can I modify a bitmap and use it later without storing or drawing

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I'm trying to do some ocr by myself in C#. I originally come from Java and this is my first "project" with C#

So I know, how you can make different ColorMatrizes to draw a processed bitmap in your application. I also do have those, but I want to use the processed picture to better analyze a picture.

Those are my methods to get a ImageAttribute

```
public static ImageAttributes ToGrayscale(Bitmap b)
public static ImageAttributes ToNegative(Bitmap b)
public static ImageAttributes ToSepia(Bitmap b)
public static ImageAttributes SetBrightness(Bitmap b, float Brightness)
public static ImageAttributes SetContrast(Bitmap b, float Contrast)
```

This is my method to draw it

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(bmp,new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 
            0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, 
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ImageAnalysis.ToGrayscale(bmp));
g.Dispose();
```

This is what I want:

```
FindLines( setConrast(toGrayscale(bmp),200) )
```

But I found no method to save the changes permanently to bitmap object. Maybe someone did this before and can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of drawing to the screen with this

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
```

You create a new bitmap and then you draw onto that bitmap, using a Graphics object obtained like this

```
Bitmap bmpNew = new Bitmap( width, height );
Graphics g = Graphics.FromBitmap( bmpNew );
```

Comment: thanks, i did this before when I tried to draw a rectangle over a the bmp (e.g. marking found lines for debuggin), but didn't realize this would work the same..

Thanks for your help